# Javascript function that should run on setTimeout() isn't being executed

Tags: javascript, dom

This function is intended to execute every second. But before executing, it is checking if the button is ready "to be clicked" on DOM.

The thing is: it only triggers once. The button disappears from the DOM and when it comes back, the function doesn't seem to be triggering again.

```
function findButton(){
    return !(document.getElementsByClassName("button--outlined")[0] == undefined)
}

function clickButton(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("button--outlined")[0].click();
}

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(){
    if(findButton())
        clickButton();
    },1000);
}
```

Comment: use `setInterval`. it is firing nearly all at once.

Comment: Worked! Thanks :D